# Two page master applied to a single page only in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a 2 page master [A]. The only difference between the two pages is the pagination. On the left page, the pagination is aligned to the left bottom of the page, and on the right one it is aligned to the right bottom.

I have another 2 page master [B], with the same difference between the two pages, that differs in the layout from the [A] page.

Is it possible to:

1. Assign the [A] master, to only the left page of a page pair, and the [B] master to the right one? When I assign the A master to the left side, it automatically get's assigned to the right side also.
2. Set up indesign, so that if I push a new page in the middle of my spread, the pages that come after it, use the correct side pagination depending on if they are left, or right pages?

Answer (score 1):

In your document setup, set the document to "Facing Pages". Then new pages will automatically assign themselves to the correct master.
[image][image]

Comment: Important note: Your master pages should be set as a spread, not individual pages.

Comment: I will check this out next week, and if it truly works, will accept this, thank you:)